# How to grow computational thinking

Tags: java, programming-languages, coding-efficiency

As a beginner java programmer,I found how I think in terms of solving a problem is more important than how much of the language and built in methods/shortcuts I know.My worst enemy in learning the programming language is when I get stuck and don't know how to approach.I was wondering is there any good book that will enhance my computation thinking and problem solving abilities?I can persevere and solve problems but I feel I lack tools/insights required.

Comment: Sorry, IMO that's out of scope for SO. That said I'd say it's more a matter of experience (try to code and design a few programs and critically review your desicions). Besides that try to think in terms of what the computer can and cannot know (not you as a human).

Comment: Experience will always be the best teacher. The more you code (and get stuck) the more you learn and improve your problem-solving approaches. Books may help, but there is ultimately no shortcut there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a tools versus techniques problem. As a craftsman, you will not learn many techniques without any tools, and simply doing things (or you will but your knowledge will be purely theoretical).

Keep learning tools and making things. In that process some sprouts of techniques will emerge. That will create more informed questions in your head and guide you further on the journey.

In other words learning Java and making stuff with it will teach you some techniques and some of that kind of thinking.

However, keep in mind the fact that Java is only one (of very many) takes on programming. Quoting great master:

> “It is not only the violin that shapes the violinist, we are all shaped by the tools we train ourselves to use, and in this respect programming languages have a devious influence: they shape our thinking habits.” 
>   ― Edsger W. Dijkstra

In terms of materials, please see the answers to [this StackExchange Programmers question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151317/thinking-skills-to-be-a-good-programmer).